# Logstash - Sudden error when trying to run local logstash instance

Tags: docker, yaml, logstash, jruby

So I'm not really sure what happened. Yesterday I was running my logstash instance locally using docker and had no issues.

Now all of my docker containers are running into this same error message when I try to run it. I can confirm that yesterday this was not an issue whatsoever:

```
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core-plugin-api/lib/logstash-core-plugin-api/version.rb:22: warning: The Psych YAML extension failed to load.
Check your env for conflicting versions of SnakeYAML
See https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/FAQs#why-does-the-psych-yaml-extension-fail-to-load-in-my-environment
[FATAL] 2021-08-10 14:41:28.832 [main] Logstash - Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (GemspecError) 
[!] There was an error while loading `logstash-core-plugin-api.gemspec`: load error: psych -- java.lang.RuntimeException: BUG: we can not copy embedded jar to temp directory
Does it try to require a relative path? That's been removed in Ruby 1.9. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core-plugin-api/logstash-core-plugin-api.gemspec:23
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >  require "logstash-core-plugin-api/version"
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------

org.jruby.exceptions.StandardError: (GemspecError) 
[!] There was an error while loading `logstash-core-plugin-api.gemspec`: load error: psych -- java.lang.RuntimeException: BUG: we can not copy embedded jar to temp directory
Does it try to require a relative path? That's been removed in Ruby 1.9. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core-plugin-api/logstash-core-plugin-api.gemspec:23
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >  require "logstash-core-plugin-api/version"
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------

        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.eval_gemspec(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:530) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.load_gemspec_uncached(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:459) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyDir.chdir(org/jruby/RubyDir.java:439) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.shared_helpers.chdir(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:65) ~[?:?]
        at uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.monitor.mon_synchronize(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/monitor.rb:235) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.shared_helpers.chdir(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:64) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.load_gemspec_uncached(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:458) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.load_gemspec(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:444) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.source.path.load_gemspec(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:151) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.source.path.load_spec_files(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:166) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1809) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.source.path.load_spec_files(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:165) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.source.path.local_specs(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:100) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.source.path.specs(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:108) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.definition.specs_for_source_changed?(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:594) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.definition.specs_changed?(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:579) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.definition.converge_paths(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:623) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.any?(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:4493) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.definition.converge_paths(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:622) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.definition.initialize(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:119) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.dsl.to_definition(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:234) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.dsl.evaluate(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:13) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.definition.build(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:34) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.definition(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:135) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_1_dot_17_dot_3.lib.bundler.setup(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:101) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.lib.bootstrap.bundler.setup!(/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:77) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:84) ~[?:?]
```

I haven't changed any code for this to happen so I'm really confused.

Any reason for this? Or at the very least how can I remove this error as it is blocking me from debugging our project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I found out the reason. I haven't been pruning my old docker images and it was adding up every time I built.

A simple command: `docker image prune` cleared the old images and everything worked again